# How do I map glfw key code to ascii code?

Tags: ascii, glfw

Is there any way I can convert GLFW Key code to ASCII code?

For letters it's easier, you just check if shift key is pressed and add 32 to the GKFW key code if it is a lowercase.  But for all the other character that requires you to hold shift (e.g "+", "@",  "%"), I just can't see how you can map them to the ASCII code without explicitly define the rule myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can register a char callback with glfwSetCharCallback(); instead of a key callback.
The Callback has the window handle and a unicode int which you can convert to a char. So for example if you press shift + a it will give you the unicode for "A".